# Opening laptop shows regular screen for split second before log-in

Tags: security, laptop, login-screen

Upon opening my laptop, the screen always flickers to the regular desktop with all the windows open and readable before going to the log-in screen.

I'm on a ThinkPad E470 currently running Ubuntu 22.04.2 with Gnome desktop, but this problem has been ongoing for a while - I think also before upgrading to 22.04. I never cared much but I'm switching to a new career where this behavior would be an (obvious) security risk.

Is this a known bug, or specific to my machine? In the latter case, any hints how to fix it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. To confirm, are you running stock Ubuntu with the Gnome desktop? Or are you running an XFCE desktop? 

Comment: Stock Ubuntu with Gnome, nothing out of the ordinary. Only thing I did to the desktop is the vertical workspaces extension, but deactivating that changes nothing.

Comment: Odd. I've not seen this with Gnome. It does affect all of my XFCE installations, though. Do you suspend the machine by closing the lid only? Or do you lock *then* close the lid? I'll see if I can duplicate the issue 

Comment: It consistently happens when I close the lid only, when I lock then close it's fine (some weird flashes happening sometimes upon opening, but nothing readable). It almost feels like the locking of the system only happens upon opening, is that possible?